# Convert sass styles to inline styles object in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm developing a component library which will be available as react components and css. To avoid redundant code and avoid react components to be dependent on stylesheets I would like to convert the sass styles I have to react inline styles something as following:

```
import buttonStyles from 'Button.scss'

...

<Button styles={buttonstyles.button__primary}>Submit</Button>
```

Where `buttonstyles.button__primary` would be the object of the react styles type for example:

```
buttonStyles = {
  button__primary: {
    marginLeft: '5px',
    background: 'red'
  },
  button__secondary: {...}
}
```

Is this possible to configure in webpack or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. config sass modules

if you created your project with **create-react-app**, only thing you need to do is adding module prefix to your filename.

rename ***Button.scss*** to ***Button.module.scss***

but if not, you should set modules option to true inside your sass-loader.

```js
// webpack.config.js

 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

#### 2.change your jsx to following

```js
import buttonStyles from 'Button.module.scss'


<Button className={buttonstyles.button__primary}>Submit</Button>
```

Comment: This is just using modules, it will still refer to css trough the className, and will not generate js object.